# Why is the result of the 32-bit program different from the 64-bit one?

Tags: c

I was working on a assignment on integer byte level representation. And I wrote a little program:

e1.c

```
int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", -2147483648 < 2147483647);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled a 32-bit version of the executable file using the C89 standard, with the command `gcc e1.c -m64 -std=c89 -g -O0 -o e1`, it worked as I expected: it printed `0` indicating that C compiler regarded the value `2147483648` as `unsigned int`, thus it converts the rest of the expression to `unsigned int`. But weirdly this relationship doesn't hold in the 64-bit version, which prints `1`.

Can anyone explain that?

Comment: I recommend compiling with `gcc -Wall -g`. The compiler might give some warning as an explanation

Comment: Better would be to print `sizeof(-2147483648)` as well as `sizeof(2147483647)`. I can bet those will be different.

Comment: unsigned int? there's no unsigned int here.

Comment: `2147483648` should be `long`, not `unsigned int` (assuming `long` is >32 bits). If `long` is 32 bits, then it should be `unsigned long`. Likely `long` is 32 bits on your 32-bit platform, and 64 bits on your 64-bit platform, thus `2147483648` is `unsigned long` on your 32-bit platform and `long` (signed) on your 64-bit platform.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It's not UB. Without a 64-bit type, and using C89, the type of 2147483648 is `unsigned long`, which can be negated just fine.

Comment: @Cornstalks how can `2147483648` be negated without a 64 bit integer type?

Comment: @WeatherVane: It can have the unary negation operator (`-`) applied to it just fine. It may not be "negative" (given it's an unsigned type), but the operator works just fine.

Answer (score 9):

[The C89 spec reads:](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.txt)

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding
>   list in which its value can be represented.  Unsuffixed decimal: `int`,
>   `long int`, `unsigned long int`; [...]

Thus, the type of the literal `2147483648` depends on the size of `int`, `long`, and `unsigned long`, respectively. Let's assume `int` is 32 bits, as it is on many platforms (and is likely the case on your platforms).

On a 32-bit platform, it's common for `long` to be 32 bits. Thus, the type of `2147483648` would be `unsigned long`.

On a 64-bit platform, it's common for `long` to be 64 bits (though some platforms, like MSVC, will still use 32 bits for `long`). Thus, the type of `2147483648` would be `long`.

This leads to the discrepancy you see. In one case, you're negating an `unsigned long`, and in the other case, you're negating a `long`.

On a 32-bit platform, `-2147483648` evaluates to `2147483648` (using the `unsigned long` type). Thus the resulting comparison is `2147483648 < 2147483647`, which evaluates to `0`.

On a 64-bit platform, `-2147483648` evaluates to `-2147483648` (using the `long` type). Thus the resulting comparison is `-2147483648 < 2147483647`, which evaluates to `1`.

Comment: Interesting... It was new to me, that not "-100" is the integer constant but "100", which is then negated by unary -. Seems illogical to me, but you are correct.

Comment: What is also interesting, is that in C11 unsuffixed decimal constants are `int`, `long int` and **`long long int`**. There seems to be no conversion to `unsigned long int` anymore.

Comment: @user694733: Correct. `long long` didn't exist in C89. When it was added in C99, the rules were changed. C11 kept the same behavior that C99 had.